# Why am I getting error occurred while installing rmagick (3.0.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rmagick

I updated my Gemfile and did a Bundler update, which created a new Gem lock file. It set RMagick to 3.0.0.

When I try to push to Heroku the update fails with the following message.

```
 An error occurred while installing rmagick (3.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.       
 Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '3.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I updated to rmagick 3.0.0 via gem install locally on my machine and it went through ok. Does the above message mean I need to update Heroku to rmagick 3.0.0 first?

Answer (score 2):

You should install ImageMagick first:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```